# Fabric.js insert after group

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have rendered a complex canvas with several layers of Fabric.js Groups, PathGroups and Paths. Many of the elements are selectable and when they are selected they should be highlighted.

Right now I'm rendering all the possible highlights together with the foundation, before the selectable objects. Really what I would prefer is to render the highlight simply when someone clicks on a Group or Path. For this I would need to insert the highlight below the selection, so is there a way of inserting a Path before a Group or another way of doing this?

Please notice, I'm not looking for element.sendBackwards(true); because there is not always the same amount of elements that the highlight should be bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it is possible to get the index of an element and move an element to a specific index! Problem solved.

```
var index = canvas.getObjects().indexOf(group1); 
canvas.moveTo(group2, index);
```